# How to get count of duplicate values with value name

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm pretty new with `Elasticsearch`, I'm using NEST library. How can I get count of duplicate values?

Here is my class:

```
public class Book
{
   public string BookName {get;set;}
   public string Author {get;set;}
}
```

This is my data:

```
BookName=X, Author=a<br>
BookName=Y, Author=a<br>
BookName=Z, Author=b<br>
BookName=C, Author=b<br>
BookName=T, Author=c<br>
```

Query result should be:

```
a- 2
b- 2
c- 1
```

I tried the following query but it doesn't work:

```
 client.Search<Book>(s => s
.Aggregations(a => a
.Terms("group_by_auth", ts => ts
        .Field(o => o.Author)
        .Size(10)
        .Aggregations(aa => aa
            .Sum("sum_value", sa => sa
                .Field(o => o.Author)
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Mapping is:

```
client= new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
        client.CreateIndex("books", c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Book>(mm => mm
            .Properties(ps=>ps
            .Text(s=>s
            .Name(a=>a.Author)
            )))
        )
```

Comment: what version of Elasticsearch are you using? What does the mapping look like for `Author`?

Comment: I edit question, I m using latest version

Comment: You don't need the inner aggregation just remove it and you have the DocCount property when you get the results. Also If you Author field has tokens you will need to do it on author.keyword field instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the count of the terms you can get it like so

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost.fiddler:9200");

            ElasticClient db = new ElasticClient(uri);

            var data = new[] {
                                new{ BookName= "X", Author="a" },
                                new{ BookName= "Y", Author="a" },
                                new{ BookName= "Z", Author="b" },
                                new{ BookName= "C", Author="b" },
                                new{ BookName= "T", Author="c" },
                            };

            db.DeleteIndex("test");

            foreach (var d in data)
            {
                db.Index(d, id => id.Index("test"));
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var items = db.Search<dynamic>(s => s.Size(0).Aggregations(aggr => aggr.Terms("group_by_auth", ts => ts.Field("author.keyword"))));

            foreach (var item in items.Aggs.Terms("group_by_auth").Buckets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "-" + item.DocCount);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("DONE");

            Console.ReadLine();
```